# What does install option of xcodebuild do

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode-build-settings

When running `xcodebuild` from the command line. What does the `install` option do?

```
xcodebuild -configuration release install
```

For the `release` scheme in this example, what switches does `install` flip?

The [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) sadly does not elaborate and the man page for `xcodebuild` makes no explicit reference to `install` other than the command takes a `<buildaction>` argument